# Powershell script defining its own ValidateSet parameter

Tags: powershell, parameters, parameter-passing

**Setup**:

I have folder containing some folders, for the sake of argument, let's say they are named `MCD1.4`, `MCD4.2`, `MCD1.3rc`, `tmp` and `personal`.

**Goal**:

I want to create a powershell script, say `process.ps1`, inside my root folder that I can run "on" one of the listed folders. However, I only want to allow the script to run on folders with names beginning with `MCD`. Also, for brevity, I want the input parameter to just be the version, without "MCD" in front. In other words, these should be allowed:

```
.\process.ps1 -version 4.2
.\process.ps1 -version 1.4
.\process.ps1 -version 1.3rc
```

but others should be invalid. So long as the folder structure remains fixed, I can achieve this as follows:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0)]
    [ValidateSet('4.2','1.4','1.3rc')
    [System.String]$version
)

Write-Host "Now processing folder MCD$version"
```

And this script behaves exactly as I want it to, as long as the folder structure remains the same.

---

However, I want to make this more dynamic, with the script taking into account the actual folder structure. What I wanted to do is this:

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem . -Directory
$options = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach ($item in $folders) {
    if ($item.Name.StartsWith("MCD")) {
        $options.Add($item.Name.Substring(3))
    }
}
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0)]
    [ValidateSet($options)
    [System.String]$version
)

Write-Host "Now processing folder MCD$version"
```

but this does not work because apparently, the `param` argument needs to be listed at the very top of the `ps1` file. Is there any way I can achieve the desired behavior of my script? The script above throws this error:

```
At C:\path\to\process.ps1:15 char:18
+     [ValidateSet($options)]
+                  ~~~~~~~~
Attribute argument must be a constant or a script block.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterAttributeArgumentNeedsToBeConstantOrScriptBlock
```

Comment: You can use a combination of `[ValidateScript()]` and `[ArgumentCompleter()]`, which is a bit cumbersome, unfortunately. I hope it's clear how you can adapat the code in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @mklement0 Very useful, thank you very much.